# Why does my flask API not return class labels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, deep-learning

I have a flask API which takes in an images and is supposed to output a prediction of its class using a pretrained model and imagenet class index.

I know that my request script is calling the API /predict endpoint because I get this output on the API side

````
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2020 19:15:08] "←[37mPOST /predict HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -```
````

I can get a prediction when I hardcode things like below, but I am not sure how to translate this to the API:

```
imagenet_class_index = json.load(open('./static/imagenet_class_index.json'))

def get_prediction(image_bytes):
    tensor = transform_image(image_bytes=image_bytes)
    outputs = model.forward(tensor)
    _, y_hat = outputs.max(1)
    predicted_idx = str(y_hat.item())
    return imagenet_class_index[predicted_idx]

with open("img059.jpg", 'rb') as f:
    image_bytes = f.read()
    print(get_prediction(image_bytes = image_bytes))
```

Here is a trimmed down version of my API

```
import io
import json

from torchvision import models
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request



app = Flask(__name__)
imagenet_class_index = json.load(open('./static/imagenet_class_index.json'))
model = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)
model.eval()


def transform_image(image_bytes):
    my_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                                        transforms.CenterCrop(244),
                                        transforms.ToTensor(),
                                        transforms.Normalize(
                                            [0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                            [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
    return my_transforms(image).unsqueeze(0)

def get_prediction(image_bytes):
    tensor = transform_image(image_bytes = image_bytes)
    outputs = model.forward(tensor)
    _, y_hat = outputs.max(1)
    predicted_idx = str(y_hat.item())
    return imagenet_class_index[predicted_idx]


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # we will get the file from the request 
        file = request.files['file']
        # convert file to bytes
        img_bytes = file.read()
        class_id, class_name = get_prediction(image_bytes = img_bytes)
        return jsonify({'class_id' : class_id, 'class_name' : class_name})

@app.route('/')
def base_route():
    return 'Greetings, Traveller!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

EDIT: base route logs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2020 19:14:59] "←[37mGET / HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
```

request.py

```
import requests

resp = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/predict",
                     files={"file": open('img059.jpg','rb')})
```

Comment: Have you tried hitting the `/` (base_route) endpoint? Have you checked the logs on the server side? If yes, can you add them to your question?

Comment: @AhmadBaracat The base route outputs the desired message when I go to localhost:5000. Added the logs to the bottom.

Comment: @WhynarySearch How are you making the requests to the API and what response are you getting? Also, are you using logging to see the output before returning it? Print the `class_id` and `class_name` before returning the response for debugging.

Comment: @Adnantaufique I thought I added that sorry. It's at the bottom now.

Comment: @WhynarySearch What's the output of the client response? Have you tried debugging the server code as I suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: @Adnantaufique The response from the server when the client makes a request is listed at the top of the question. There is no other output from the client or server when a request is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are simply not printing the response.  Your client script should be

request.py

```py
import requests

resp = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/predict",
                     files={"file": open('img059.jpg','rb')})

result = resp.json()
print(f"Class Id:{result['class_id']}, Class Name: {result['class_name']}")
```

You should be able to see the results now.